# Get form popup upon successful submission

Tags: javascript, html

How do I go about getting this form to display "Submitted" using basic javascript popup window upon successful submission?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Site :: </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="css/wicahost.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="css/global.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <?php require_once('inc/php/clearfieldJs.php'); ?> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#splashtease").RSV({
        rules: [
        "required,emAdd,Please enter your email address.",
        "valid_email,emAdd,Please enter a valid email address.",
        ]
    });
});
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <script src="http://www.benjaminkeen.com/software/rsv/jquery/jquery.rsv.js"></script>
    <div id="splashTeaserBox">
    <h1 class="wicasplashcenter">Signup!</h1>
    <div class="wicasplashcenter">Captivating interests and inspiring collaboration.</div>
    <form id="splashtease" action="inc/subscribe.php" method="post">
    <?php $usrBrowser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']; $todayDt = date('Y-m-d');  ?>
        <input type="text" name="emAdd" class="splashtease" value="Your Email Address ..." onFocus="clearText(this)" />
        <input type="hidden" name="brwsr" value="<?php echo $usrBrowser; ?>" style="margin:0; padding:0;" />
        <input type="hidden" name="dt" value="<?php echo $todayDt; ?>" style="margin:0; padding:0;" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="" class="splashteasesub" />
    </form>
</div><!--splashTeaserBox--></body>
</html>
```

**PHP**

```
 <?php
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="root"; // Mysql username 
$password=""; // Mysql password 
$db_name="dnbame"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="subscriber"; // Table name

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

/* Obliterate bad input */
$goodEmail = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['emAdd']);
$goodBrowser = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['brwsr']);
$goodDate = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['dt']);


$sql= "INSERT INTO subscriber (Email, Browser, DateSubscribed) VALUES('$goodEmail','$goodBrowser','$goodDate')";

$result = mysql_query($sql);
if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid Email, please retry.');
}
else{
    echo var success;
}

?>
```

Comment: Your php is outputing 'var success' which seems to be in error. So normally the server only responds to requests and the echo output would be its response on successful submit. Normally the response is a new page which in which you may test for whatever you write in 'echo whatever' and rewrite using javascript.

Answer (score 0):

A basic example:

In subscribe.php, change:

```
else{
    echo var success;
}
```

to:

```
else {
    echo "<html><body onload=\"alert('Submitted');\"><p>Submission successful.</p></body></html>";
}
```

Comment: THis throws error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';'

Comment: change `echo '<html><body onload="alert('Submitted');"><p>Submission successful.</p></body></html>';` to `echo "<html><body onload=\"alert('Submitted');\"><p>Submission successful.</p></body></html>";`

Answer (score 0):

@user886187's solution will reload the page upon submission and then display a JavaScript pop-up when the page has reloaded.

You might want to submit the form and then display the pop-up without reloading the page. In that case you need to submit the form via Ajax, and then alert "submitted" in the callback function:

```
function callback() {
    alert('submitted');
}
```

Here's a tutorial on how to submit a form via Ajax:
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/submit-a-form-without-page-refresh-using-jquery/

Comment: So you would like the work done for you, rather than learn how to do it yourself. I suggest you add bounty to the question.

Answer (score 0):

put this code in your subcribe.php

```
else {
 header  ('Location: formPage.php?message=Success');
}
```

and this code inside head of formPage.php

```
<head>

<?php  if ($_GET['message']) {echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Form Submited Successfully");</script>';} ?>

</head>
```